# How to make some protocol methods only available for specific iOS version?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Is it possible to have something close to this:

```
protocol FooBarDelegate: class {
    func foo()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        func bar()
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
protocol FooBarDelegate: class {
    func foo()

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func bar()
}
```